# Why am I glowing blue?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

During Ozen's training mission in the second layer of Hello Abyss mode, an enemy hit me and I started glowing blue. The effect persisted even after I returned to Ozen's Seeker Camp. Why am I glowing blue and how do I make it stop?

[image: Riko glowing blue]

Answer (score 2):

That should be poison, the blue-type one to be precise.
The good new is that it "only" speeds up your hunger loss.
The bad new is that since this is a Made In Abyss game, poison does not "time out" like it does in many other games (see: Demon Soul's Swamp of Sorrow) but will keep you company forever, until you use an antidote. That hopefully you have unlocked, otherwise... have fun with your increased metabolism for a while!

BTW, since you mentioned poison, I think you may want to be quite careful should you meet some "friendly" creature that you may probably guess if you actually saw the original anime / manga. There is a special type of poison that can't be cured at all unless you have access to some very specific  gimmick in the game (missable and worthy of the "Guide dang it!" page on TV Tropes...) and... well, let's just say that many player consider saving while under the effect of that status a possible softlock cause... This should not be a real problem in the "Hello Abyss" tutorial mode, but please take care when you start the REAL game and things gets a lot worse...

Comment: You can use the "Give Up" option if you get stuck after being poisoned. You'll lose any items you found during the expedition, but you'll be cured of poison.